# Solving Laplace equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, vector, finite-element-method, vector-calculus

I was trying to solve Laplace's equation for a spherical capacitor, which is not difficult by hand, just to figure out the commands so I can eventually try something more complicated. Then, I ran into trouble.

I tried to use spherical coordinates, and I got an error of a non real answer, or sometimes null.

```
leqn = ( Laplacian[V[r,\[Theta],\[Phi]],{r,\[Theta],\[Phi]},"Spherical" ] ==0 //Simplify)
a=1; b=10;
NDSolveValue[{leqn,V[a,\[Theta],\[Phi]]==1,V[b,\[Theta],\[Phi]]==0},V,{r,a,b},{\[Theta],0,\[Pi]},{\[Phi],0,2*\[Pi]}]
```

---

So I figured I'd try in Cartesian coordinates in order to figure out my error; it worked:

```
a=1;b=5
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}] == 0,
DirichletCondition[u[x,y] == 1,Sqrt[x^2+y^2] ==a ],
DirichletCondition[u[x,y] == 0,Sqrt[x^2+y^2] ==b]
}, u, {x, y} \[Element]Annulus[{0,0},{a,b}]]

Plot3D[%[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Annulus[{0,0},{a,b}]]
```

But then if I try to be a little more explicit about the boundary conditions it stops working:

```
a=1;b=5
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}]== 0,
u[x,y] == If[Norm[{x,y}]==a,1],
DirichletCondition[u[x,y] == 0,Sqrt[x^2+y^2] ==b]
}, u, {x, y} \[Element]Annulus[{0,0},{a,b}]]
Plot3D[%[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Annulus[{0,0},{a,b}]]
```

---

Anyway, I still can't figure out why the explicit form of the boundary condition didn't work.

Furthermore, I don't see why the polar version didn't work.

Comment: Your spherical coordinate code works for me v11.3.  Even changing the bc's to functions of theta and phi works.  You could try clearing the kernel unless your version is too old.

Comment: @BillWatts I tried both on the Wolfram programing cloud, and in Mathematica version "10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)". I tried restarting the kernel. It still didn't work

Comment: @BillWatts 10.4.0 gave me the following error for my spherical coordinate code:  

 NDSolveValue::femcnmd: "The PDE coefficient {{r,0,0},{0,1/r,0},{0,0,Csc[\[Theta]]^2/r}} does not evaluate to a numeric matrix of dimensions {3,3} at the coordinate {1.`,0.`,0.`}"

Comment: @BillWatts "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" in the cloud just gives up and it looks like the kernel quits

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get.

```
leqn = (Laplacian[V[r, θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ},  "Spherical"] == 0 // Simplify)
a = 1; b = 10;

sol = NDSolveValue[{leqn, V[a, θ, ϕ] == 1, 
   V[b, θ, ϕ] == 0}, 
  V, {r, a, b}, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2*π}]

Plot[sol[r, 0, 0], {r, a, b}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Get a little fancier.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{leqn, V[a, θ, ϕ] == 1, 
   V[b, θ, ϕ] == Sin[θ]}, 
  V, {r, a, b}, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2*π}]

Plot[{sol[r, 0, 0], sol[r, π/4, 0], sol[r, π/2, 0]}, {r, a, 
  b}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
gifs = Table[
   Plot[sol[r, θ, π/2], {θ, 0, π}, 
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {θ, V}, 
    PlotLabel -> "r = " <> ToString[PaddedForm[N[r], {3, 2}]]], {r, a,
     b, (b - a)/50}];

ListAnimate[gifs]
```

[image]

V11.3 windows 10.